# How to use the -spec functionality in erlang

Tags: types, casting, erlang

I'm writing up a small erlang service and I would like to put constraints on my types.

I've found the [-spec](http://www.erlang.org/eeps/eep-0008.html) functionality, and it looks to me like this is a way of 'locking' the signatures of functions to specific types.

My example would be a function like:

```
fib(N) when N < 3 ->
    1;
fib(N) ->
    fib(N-1) + fib(N-2).
```

adding the line

```
-spec fib_cps(pos_integer()) -> pos_integer().
```

should make sure the method atleast returns the correct type, but this does not seem to be the case..

for If I change the function to :

```
fib(N) when N < 3 ->
    ok;
fib(N) ->
    not_ok.
```

the code still compiles, fine and even runs.

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: BTW, your type spec should look like `-spec fib_cps(pos_integer()) -> pos_integer().` (note the empty parentheses), otherwise Dialyzer thinks that you mean the atom `pos_integer`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Compiler skips those comments. But you can use dialyzer to do static code analysis. This tool will warn you about spec violations.

Comment: Does that mean that inorder to ensure 'stable' code you have to run the dialyzer tool ontop of the compiler? Is this how you get around the entire typechecking problem?

Comment: @MartinKristiansen Yes, if you want stable production code, you should run dialyzer. Maybe not every build, but periodically. For example, you can integrate it with daily build system, if you use one.

Answer (score 1):

As [werewindle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/219939/werewindle) says in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8505933), `-spec` is only used for analysis, not as part of the signature.  If you want to verify input types, you can include checks for the type in the guard.  So, in your example, you can do:

```
fib(N) when is_integer(N), N > 0, N < 3 ->
    1;
fib(N) when is_integer(N), N >= 3 ->
    fib(N-1) + fib(N-2).
```

Or, more idiomatically, since there are only two legitimate base cases:

```
fib(1) -> 1;
fib(2) -> 1;
fib(N) when is_integer(N), N >= 3 ->
    fib(N-1) + fib(N-2).
```

This would prevent you from doing something like `fib(bogus)` or `fib(0.5)` or even `fib(-1)`.  If you try, it will fail with a `badmatch` at runtime.

Note: the only functions you can use in a [guard](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id79005) are built-in functions allowed by the runtime.  Most of them are in the [`erlang`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html) module.

Comment: I see, but what I really would like is some sort of static typechecking, like in ML. Meaning that I would like to specify a type 
A := C | D.
And then define the method to have type forinstance (_ -> A).
Do you know of languages with good concurrency mechanisms that are able to do that sorta thing?

Comment: @MartinKristiansen: dialyzer is a standard erlang tool. It is shipped with erlang and should be used in any erlang project. Yes, static analysis is not part of the compiler, but anyway you can do this anytime you want. Imagine, if C preprocessor would be separate tool from compiler. It would be somehow uncomfortable, but ok.